# dock/undock functionality like chrome-dev tool in my chrome extention

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am creating a google chrome extension which will load my web-app i have a map component on it, i want this map component to be attachable/deattachable (when user drag it from its position it will open itself in new window, or when user close map's window it will attach to my main app)

main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    // Center window on screen.
    var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
    var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
    var width = 500;
    var height = 300;

    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        id: "helloWorldID",
        outerBounds: {
          width: width,
          height: height,
          left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
          top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
        }
    });

    chrome.app.window.onClosed.addListener(function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    });
    chrome.app.window.onFullscreened.addListener(function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    })


});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    .innermenu {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #f00;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Main File</h1>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="innermenu">MAP</div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.js

```
var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var id = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#menu").sortable({
        out: function( event, ui ) {
            chrome.app.window.create('map.html', {
                id: "map" + (id++),
                outerBounds: {
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
                    top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So my question is how to make communication between map.html(which open in seperate window) with index.html(my main app).

Comment: First off, it's _extremely important_ that what you have is not an extension but an app. It's a completely different set of rules.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? As in, what is not covered by [Messaging guide](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging)?

Comment: @Xan I want when user close "map"  then somehow i want to send notification to main.js, but i am not able to get close event of map.